# Ionic 4 with angular7 : Issue creating loader service (async/await)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, async-await, ionic4

I am trying to create a wrapper service `LoaderService` on top of Ionic4 `LoadingController`.

Here is my code snippet for `LoaderService`

```
export class LoaderService {

    loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement;

    constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {
        console.log('constructor called');
        this.createLoader();
    }

    async createLoader() {
        this.loader = await this.loadingController.create({
            message: 'Loading',
        });
        console.log('loader created');
    }

    async showLoader() {
        await this.loader.present();
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.loader.dismiss();
    }

}
```

> Goal to achieve: Using Service I want to create a single instance of loader in my app and allow components to show and dismiss the loader while making API calls.

Problem: When I use my `LoaderService` inside my component I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'present' of undefined`.
This happens because `showLoader` is called before the loader is created asynchronously.

Here is the code of my component while making API call and calling loader:

```
getTopHeadlines() {
    this._loaderService.showLoader();
    this._newsApiServcie.getTopHeadLines('in')
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.articleList = res.articles;
            this._loaderService.hideLoader();
        });
}
```

Also, have a look at the browser console
[image]

Comment: Why not combine create and show loader into one async method? I understand you want to optimize here and only “create once” but this is not going to win you much anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since loading controller gets destroyed on dismiss, so even though your intent is noble (to have one loader overlay in memory and then show/hide it) - this approach seems suboptimal.

There is no harm in creating loader overlay dynamically. I would modify your code to be something like the below:

**Loader service:**

```
export class LoaderService {

    loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement;

    constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    }

    showLoader() {
        if (this.loader) { 
            this.loader.present()
        } else {
            this.loader = this.loadingController.create({
                message: 'Loading',
            }).then(() => {
                this.loader.present()
            })
        }
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.loader.dismiss();
        this.loader = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't you think, calling showLoader multiple times without calling hideLoader or dismiss will have more than one instances of loader in memory?

Comment: I think this can be a valid concern, I added a small snippet of code to ensure that every time showLoader() is called if loader exists already it will get dismissed before a new one loader is created and with no reference to previous loader existing GC should clean up the memory.

Comment: if the loader is already present, there is no need to set it to null and again create a new one, we can call present() on the old instance only.

Comment: makes sense actually;) I added the code. BTW interested to see if this works for you and I might as well implement this in my app